# Thesis help! This sentence is really bothering me. Please explain why I feel bothered

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

This sentence is really bothering me. Does this look right to anyone? If not, can someone write why? Thanks.

> Only to the extent that John and Jane are willing to let go of the pretense and show themselves for who they are will they be free to enjoy a true marriage and enter honestly into the sacred covenant.

I am not soliciting writing advice. I have made a good faith effort to research the question and have come to this site only upon mature consideration.

Comment: I'm glad you've researched the question and come upon mature consideration. That's commendable. However, ... What is the question? There are no questions asked in your post. What do you think is troublesome/problematic/ungrammatical/vague/irregular about that sentence, which is, for the record, completely grammatical, if peculiar? But most sentences are peculiar; they all occur in specific circumstances.

Comment: When you did your research, what did you look up and where?

Comment: The only thing that bothers me in the sentence is that you are essentially saying they will only be free to _X_ to the extent that they _Y_, which is strange. You're comparing apples and oranges here. They cannot enjoy marriage to the extent that they let go—they can enjoy marriage _once_ they let go, or only _if_ they let go. Or the extent that they are willing to let go determines _whether/to what degree_ they can enjoy marriage.

Comment: @Janus: I don't see a problem with the semantics. The *more* they're willing to Y *("let go")*, the more they will be free/able to X *("enjoy a true marriage")*. Neither action is necessarily "binary" (do/don't), so it's fine to say the extent to which you (are able to) do one is directly proportional to the extent to which you (choose to) do the other.

Comment: I agree that they are both gradable, but to me, letting go and showing oneself for what one really is are both measured in a different conceptual scale from enjoying a marriage. It's sort of akin to saying that you can only run to the extent that your legs are long—running is measured in speed, legs in length. That's why it sounds better to me to say that the extent they are willing to let go determines to what degree they can enjoy the marriage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you have chosen for consideration is a construction where two degrees are asserted to be commensurate.

Consider the following from Shakespeare's *Henry V*:

> By how much better than my word I am, / By so much shall I falsify men's hope

You could rephrase it as:

> To the extent that my deeds surpass what I have promised, my critics will reevaluate me.

The construction works because it is easy to identify the two quantities being compared.

In the sample sentence, the quantity in the standard of comparison *the extent that John and Jane are willing to let go of [their pretenses] and show themselves for who they are]*, is easy enough to identify.

In the clause containing the object of comparison,

> ...[they will] be free to enjoy a true marriage and enter honestly into the sacred covenant

there is ambiguous in the quantity to be considered. It could be their feeling of freedom which is equal in extent to their willingness to drop pretenses, etc., or it could be the truth-level of their marriage and the honesty-level with which they enter into the sacred covenant which is equal in extent to their willingness to drop pretenses, etc.

To make the sentence easier to parse, revise it with less embedding in the second clause.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this - the only thing I could see wrong was a minor typo (which I just corrected anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as a whole is grammatically correct, and will cause no trouble to somebody who is used to reading dense academic prose.

It looks weird when you slow down and study the sentence in detail, because the sentence's complicated structure produces fragments like this:

> ... who they are will they ...

But the person who marks your thesis won't do that. So don't change a thing.

(I previously suggested you put a comma between *are* and *will*, but on reflection, it harms as much as it helps.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify this sentence. Original Sentence:
Only to the extent that John and Jane are willing to let go of the pretense and show themselves for who they are will they be free to enjoy a true marriage and enter honestly into the sacred covenant.

We can replace some verbs with things that still keep the sentence's structure:

Only once John and Jane are willing to let go and show themselves will they be free to enjoy and enter.

See how much more understandable it becomes when we simplify it?

Comment: It's simpler, but at the cost of the precise nuance of meaning. I would normally call that a good trade off, but not in a thesis paper.  For a thesis, the writer has to demonstrate they have grasped these nuances, and the reader is assumed to be willing and able to read dense academic prose.

Comment: By the way, I'm not the one who downvoted you. I wish people wouldn't downvote anonymously.

Comment: Original does seem a bit backwards and stilty. How about: "John and Jane will be free to... only to the extent that they are willing to let go..."

Comment: I'm only simplifying it so that the asker can understand the sentence structure. Once you add back all the rest the meaning will still be clear.

Answer (score 0):

A pair of "the"s made the me feel a mite disconnected from the sentence. Removing the two words crossed out below made me a bit more comfortable:

> Only to the extent that John and Jane are willing to let go of
>   <del>the</del> pretense and show themselves for who they are will they
>   be free to enjoy a true marriage and enter honestly into
>   <del>the</del> sacred covenant.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You might be right, but it might also be the case that the words "pretense" and "sacred covenant" refer to previously defined concepts, in which case they're needed.